# Change agenda hour from 6 am to 6 am tomorrow

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to set FullCalendar so it shows hours from 6am to 6am the next day. I can set `minTime=6`, but what should I put as `maxTime`? Thanks!

This is the full code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "/getfullcalendar",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( retevents ) {
      var retevents = retevents;
      $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaDay,listWeek',
            },
        firstDay: 1,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        navLinks: true,
        minTime: "06:00:00",

       // What to put here
       // for the same time tomorrow (6am)? 
        maxTime: "24:00:00",

        height: 'auto',
        events: retevents,

    });
    });
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maxTime: "30:00:00"
```

24 hours + 6 hours for the next day

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the

```
allDaySlot: true
```

option.  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/allDaySlot/

Comment: That just adss space to display all-day events, it does not affect the number of hours shown after minTime, unfortunately.